# regex matcher check in if logic not working

Tags: java, regex

Hi, you can see my code below. I have some strings `Country`, `rank` and `grank` in my code, initially they will be null, but if regex is mached, it should change the value. But even if regex is matched it is not changing the value it is always null. If I remove all if statements and append the string it works fine, but if match is not found it is throwing an exception. Please let me know how can I check this in if logic.

```
System.err.println(content);
Pattern c = Pattern.compile("NAME=\"(.*)\" RANK");
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\" RANK=\"(.*)\"");
Pattern gr = Pattern.compile("\" TEXT=\"(.*)\" SOURCE");
Matcher co = c.matcher(content);
Matcher ra = r.matcher(content);
Matcher gra = gr.matcher(content);
co.find();
ra.find();
gra.find();
String country = null;
String Rank = null;
String Grank = null;
if (co.matches()) {
   country = co.group(1);
}
if (ra.matches()) {
   Rank = ra.group(1);
}
if (gra.matches()) {
   Grank = gra.group(1);
}
```

Comment: First of all you shouldn't have variable with Maj as first character  not `String Rank` --> `String rank`same for `Grank`.
Second are you sure they match your patterns ?

Comment: what is Maj? I am sure regex is matching, because it always worked for me where initially m y logic was like this String country = co.group(1); similarly for all other strings, problem comes when for some input variables, regex will not match and it throws an exception, I want to handle that in an if logic so that it should be null or the matched regex value, hope you understood my problem

Comment: maj = Upper case ;) 
Can you add the original string content you try to parse ;)

Comment: String is too big to paste,

Comment: you can replace `.matches()` calls with `.find()` calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape a single `\` - use double `\\` then it should work.

Tried this?

```
while (co.find()) {
  System.out.print("Start index: " + co.start());
  System.out.print(" End index: " + co.end() + " ");
  System.out.println(co.group());
}
```

Comment: problem is not with regex, it is with if logic, regex worked perfectly when there were no if logic

Comment: Thanks this worked absolutely fine for me I made all string null initially and if passes while, I have changed the string value. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I can't make your program work with / without the `if` so it's not a problem of logic but just a problem that it doesn't match the string for me

So I changed it to get something working, maybe you can use it :)

```
String content = "NAME=\"salut\" RANK=\"pouet\" TEXT=\"text\" SOURCE";
System.out.println(content);
System.out.println(content.replaceAll(("NAME=\"(.*)\"\\sRANK=\"(.*)\"\\sTEXT=\"(.*)\" SOURCE"), "$1---$2---$3"));
```

Output

```
  NAME="salut" RANK="pouet" TEXT="text" SOURCE
  salut---pouet---text
```